# Definition Of 'Inner Derivation'

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, modules

I need a useful definition of an inner derivation of modules or even better a good reference to read about.

Comment: @rschwieb Analogue definition.

Comment: What is your analogue for ring multiplication in a module?

Comment: @rschieb Let $R$ be a ring and $M$ a $R$-module. With a derivation of modules I mean a $R$-linear map $D: R \rightarrow M $ with Leipniz rule. What do you mean with ring multiplication - I dont see the obstacle?

Comment: But as $D$ maps from $R$ all is fine. $ab \in R$

Comment: Sorry, typed comment before I saw you picked the domain to be $R$ then. OK, so you want it to be from $R\to M$. I hadn't anticipated that, and I agree there's no problem with defining it this way, except that you probably stick to $R$ commutative to make it a bimodule.

Comment: It sounds like an interesting question, and I wish I knew more about derivations so that I could tackle it better.

Comment: Does "useful definition" mean you saw this mentioned somewhere and you want an "understandable definition"? If so, where was it? Or perhaps this a concept you believe should exist but haven't seen anywhere? In any case, "inner" typically refers to conjugation and I don't see how one can use conjugation to induce a derivation if your rings are commutative.

Comment: @rghthndsd I am dealing with the following map, which is supposed to be an inner derivation: $D: G \rightarrow M$ via $g \mapsto (g-1)n$ where $G$ is a torsionfree group, $M$ a $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$-module and $n$ an element out of $M$, such that $\phi(n)=1$ with $\phi: M \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$. I can neither check the Leipniz rule nor any connection to conjugation in order to be 'inner'.

Comment: I suggest adding this detail to your question. I would also add information on how $G$ acts on $M$ (if known) and exactly what type of map $\varphi$ is. Finally, it would also be very helpful to include a reference for where this is coming from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found, for my concerns, a very good definition and explanation in ['Groups, Trees and Projective Modules'](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/11481http://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/BFb0088140/page/1) by W.Dicks on p.16.

Answer (score 0):

Another, even better source for these kind of derivations is K.S. Browns "Cohomology of Groups" (p. 89). He use to call these derivations **principal**.